# C# NullReferenceException while EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, eventargs

I get a NullRefernceException even though I subscribed to the event in an Start Methode.

Where I create my Event:

```
public EventHandler<CustomArgs> ClickEvent;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked");
        CustomArgs args = new CustomArgs();
        args.Name = gebäude.ToString();
        args.Level = Level;
        args.MenuePosition = Menue;

        ClickEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
```

Where I subscribe to my Event:

```
private void Start()
    {
        miene.ClickEvent += ClickEvent;
        Debug.Log("Event Addedet");
    }

    private void ClickEvent(object sender, CustomArgs e)
    {
        //some useless stuff 
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Events are `null` when no-one has subscribed. Fortunately, modern C# makes this easy:

```cs
ClickEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
```

With older language versions, you need to be more verbose:

```cs
var handler = ClickEvent;
if (handler != null) handler(this, args);
```

They mean exactly the same thing.

As a small optimisation, you may wish to defer creating the `CustomArgs` object until you know someone cares, though:

```cs
ClickEvent?.Invoke(this, new CustomArgs {
    Name = gebäude.ToString(),
    Level = Level,
    MenuePosition = Menue
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is fixing the error, but not the problem.
I need this Invoke because I want to do something when I get the mouse down

Comment: @Manubown if it is throwing an exception, then you **haven't subscribed to the event**. So: subscribe to the event!

Comment: miene.ClickEvent += (s, args) =>
        {
            //some useless stuff
        };
Isn't that a subscribe

Comment: @Manubown yes, but if the event is still null: **you haven't done that** - or maybe not on the right target object

Comment: i have writen the subscribe command in the Update method and the OnMouseDown is a button click so I thing the Update method will be done bevor the button click.